# Angular2 D3 - CSS styling is not applied

Tags: css, d3.js, angular

I'm having trouble getting my CSS styles applied properly to a D3 generated `<text>` element created within an Angular2 component.

Apparently it was (is?!) possible to use the special CSS selectors `* >>>` to achieve the desired styling (see http://plnkr.co/edit/Hc56mk07v0GD4W8rVzz1?p=preview for an example) but the same approach doesn't work for me. (I'm on RC4 and D3 4.1)

The element does have the proper class attribute set `class="label-text"` but no styling is applied despite `* >>> .label-text { ... }` definition in the referenced CSS file.

Can someone shed some light on this, do we have to deactivated the viewencapsulation or is there another way?

Comment: Maybe your plunker doesnt show what you have described so far. Is it incomplete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after *a lot* of debugging I finally figured out what the problem is.
I'm accessing the svg element via:

```
this.htmlElement = this.element.nativeElement;
this.host = d3.select(this.element.nativeElement);
this.svg = this.host.append('svg');
```

For some reason the `* >>>` doesn't work here.
If however I adjust the css file to

```
:host .label-text {
    ...
}
```

it works just fine.

Hope that helps someone else with the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had any issues with the `* >>>` selectors when i have done something with d3.js, maybe you just have a typo somewhere.

Here is plunker with angular RC4 and D3.js v4.2 with some text created with d3 and css applied to it with `* >>>` selector. http://plnkr.co/edit/Nkv5S5DGHmWTiMoxBcgU?p=preview